# Boost::multi_array performance question

Tags: c++, performance, boost, boost-multi-array

I am trying to compare the performance of boost::multi_array to native dynamically allocated arrays, with the following test program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS 
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const int X_SIZE = 200;
    const int Y_SIZE = 200;
    const int ITERATIONS = 500;
    unsigned int startTime = 0;
    unsigned int endTime = 0;

    // Create the boost array
    typedef boost::multi_array<double, 2> ImageArrayType;
    ImageArrayType boostMatrix(boost::extents[X_SIZE][Y_SIZE]);

    // Create the native array
    double *nativeMatrix = new double [X_SIZE * Y_SIZE];

    //------------------Measure boost----------------------------------------------
    startTime = ::GetTickCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < Y_SIZE; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < X_SIZE; ++x)
            {
                boostMatrix[x][y] = 2.345;
            }
        }
    }
    endTime = ::GetTickCount();
    printf("[Boost] Elapsed time: %6.3f seconds\n", (endTime - startTime) / 1000.0);

    //------------------Measure native-----------------------------------------------
    startTime = ::GetTickCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < Y_SIZE; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < X_SIZE; ++x)
            {
                nativeMatrix[x + (y * X_SIZE)] = 2.345;
            }
        }
    }
    endTime = ::GetTickCount();
    printf("[Native]Elapsed time: %6.3f seconds\n", (endTime - startTime) / 1000.0);

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following results:

```
[Boost] Elapsed time: 12.500 seconds
[Native]Elapsed time:  0.062 seconds
```

I can't believe multi_arrays are that much slower. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

I assume caching is not an issue since I am doing writes to memory.

EDIT: This was a debug build. Per Laserallan's suggest I did a release build:

```
[Boost] Elapsed time:  0.266 seconds
[Native]Elapsed time:  0.016 seconds
```

Much closer. But 16 to 1 still seems to high to me.

Well, no definitive answer, but I'm going to move on and leave my real code with native arrays for now.

Accepting Laserallan's answer because it was the biggest flaw in my test.

Thanks to all.

Comment: try swapping the order for native and boost, or run native and boost in separate in their own main. working set issues for your program may slow down the first test

Comment: I did try swapping the order - no difference. Thanks.

Comment: i also recommend you to change your formula to "y + (x * Y_SIZE)", so that it's equal to what the boost one does. (at least that's how builtin multi dimensional arrays behave). and double check your optimize options. maybe you can put the optimize one step higher or so?

Comment: ... because as it's now, the native array test,in the inner loop, always has adjacent memory accesses. although x16 is not *that* much slower. i think it's reasonable.

Comment: I just tried this same test, and with GCC at least, I needed to specify at least -O2 optimization for boost multi array to be equivalent performance to the native array at the same level. (This was after switching the array indexing in the boost version - it was about 3x slower without that fix)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you building release or debug?

If running in debug mode, the boost array might be really slow because their template magic isn't inlined properly giving lots of overhead in function calls. I'm not sure how multi array is implemented though so this might be totally off :)

Perhaps there is some difference in storage order as well so you might be having your image stored column by column and writing it row by row. This would give poor cache behavior and may slow down things.

Try switching the order of the X and Y loop and see if you gain anything.
There is some info on the storage ordering here: 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

EDIT:
Since you seem to be using the two dimensional array for image processing you might be interested in checking out boosts image processing library [gil](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html).

It might have arrays with less overhead that works perfectly for your situation.

Comment: Switching X and Y made no difference. Thanks.

Comment: I am in fact doing image processing. Thanks for the link. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 34):

On my machine using

```
g++ -O3 -march=native -mtune=native --fast-math -DNDEBUG test.cpp -o test && ./test
```

I get

```
[Boost] Elapsed time:  0.020 seconds
[Native]Elapsed time:  0.020 seconds
```

However changing `const int ITERATIONS` to `5000` I get

```
[Boost] Elapsed time:  0.240 seconds
[Native]Elapsed time:  0.180 seconds
```

then with `ITERATIONS` back to `500` but `X_SIZE` and `Y_SIZE` set to `400` I get a much more significant difference

```
[Boost] Elapsed time:  0.460 seconds
[Native]Elapsed time:  0.070 seconds
```

finally inverting the inner loop for the `[Boost]` case so it looks like

```
    for (int x = 0; x < X_SIZE; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < Y_SIZE; ++y)
        {
```

and keeping `ITERATIONS`, `X_SIZE` and `Y_SIZE` to `500`, `400` and `400` I get

```
[Boost] Elapsed time:  0.060 seconds
[Native]Elapsed time:  0.080 seconds
```

If I invert the inner loop also for the `[Native]` case (so it is in the wrong order for that case), I get, unsurprisingly,

```
[Boost] Elapsed time:  0.070 seconds
[Native]Elapsed time:  0.450 seconds
```

I am using `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5` on Ubuntu 10.10

So in conclusion:

- With *proper optimization* boost::multi_array does its job as expected
- The order on which you access your data *does matter*

Comment: Should change "= 2.345" to sth like "*= 1.0001", like Drew Dormann said.

Answer (score 11):

**Your test is flawed.**

- In a DEBUG build, boost::MultiArray lacks the optimization pass that it sorely needs.  (Much more than a native array would)
- In a RELEASE build, your compiler will look for code that can be removed outright and **most of your code is in that category**.

What you're likely seeing is the result of your optimizing compiler seeing that most or all of your "native array" loops can be removed.  The same is theoretically true of your boost::MultiArray loops, but MultiArray is probably complex enough to defeat your optimizer.

**Make this small change to your testbed** and you'll see more true-to-life results:  Change both occurances of "`= 2.345` " with "`*= 2.345` " and compile again with optimizations.  This will prevent your compiler from discovering that the outer loop of each test is redundant.

I did it and got a speed comparison closer to 2:1.

Comment: I don't believe the native code is being optimized out. Added a print of an arbitrary element in the array after the loop. No change to native time.

Comment: I clarified my description, Steve.  Hope that helps.  Even with an arbitrary print, the loop has to run once, not 500 times.

Comment: Good point. But strangely, I don't get any change in time from going to *= 2.345.

Comment: Playing "outsmart the compiler" can be tricky.  The change I mentioned worked with gcc4, but it looks like you're using VC++.  The arbitrary print you added...try putting that inside the "500" loop.  All told, I got the same 16:1 difference you describe until I fooled the optimizer.

Comment: I did two things to verify that ths full loop is running: changed size to 2x X 2y X 5 iter and observed 10 breakpoint stops; changed calculation to set each element to x * y * i and verified last element. It seems to be running the full loop.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using Blitz++ instead. I tried out Blitz, and its performance is on par with C-style array!

Check out your code with Blitz added below:

---

```
#include <windows.h>
#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS 
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <blitz/array.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const int X_SIZE = 200;
    const int Y_SIZE = 200;
    const int ITERATIONS = 500;
    unsigned int startTime = 0;
    unsigned int endTime = 0;

    // Create the boost array
    typedef boost::multi_array<double, 2> ImageArrayType;
    ImageArrayType boostMatrix(boost::extents[X_SIZE][Y_SIZE]);


    //------------------Measure boost----------------------------------------------
    startTime = ::GetTickCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < Y_SIZE; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < X_SIZE; ++x)
            {
                boostMatrix[x][y] = 2.345;
            }
        }
    }
    endTime = ::GetTickCount();
    printf("[Boost] Elapsed time: %6.3f seconds\n", (endTime - startTime) / 1000.0);

    //------------------Measure blitz-----------------------------------------------
    blitz::Array<double, 2> blitzArray( X_SIZE, Y_SIZE );
    startTime = ::GetTickCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < Y_SIZE; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < X_SIZE; ++x)
            {
                blitzArray(x,y) = 2.345;
            }
        }
    }
    endTime = ::GetTickCount();
    printf("[Blitz] Elapsed time: %6.3f seconds\n", (endTime - startTime) / 1000.0);


    //------------------Measure native-----------------------------------------------
    // Create the native array
    double *nativeMatrix = new double [X_SIZE * Y_SIZE];

    startTime = ::GetTickCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < Y_SIZE; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < X_SIZE; ++x)
            {
                nativeMatrix[x + (y * X_SIZE)] = 2.345;
            }
        }
    }
    endTime = ::GetTickCount();
    printf("[Native]Elapsed time: %6.3f seconds\n", (endTime - startTime) / 1000.0);



    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the result in debug and release.

DEBUG:

```
Boost  2.093 secs 
Blitz  0.375 secs 
Native 0.078 secs
```

RELEASE:

```
Boost  0.266 secs
Blitz  0.016 secs
Native 0.015 secs
```

I used MSVC 2008 SP1 compiler for this.

Can we now say good-bye to C-stlye array? =p

Comment: Just a note: you shouldnt simply download version .9 from their website. The best way is to check out from their CVS repository. The instruction is here: http://sourceforge.net/cvs/?group_id=63961
Seems like you are developing for Windows platform; in that case, look for Blitz-VS2005.zip.

Comment: This seems to have the loop orders incorrect for blitz and boost. For me, flipping the y and x loops only for boost/blitz produces better results making all three roughly equivalent.

Comment: C++ arrays are row-major ordered. So please change the loop order to match C++ native arrays. In my computer: >  [Boost] Elapsed time:  3.791 seconds >  [Blitz] Elapsed time:  0.124 seconds >  Native]Elapsed time:  0.531 seconds for the 800 x 800 x 500 case.

Answer (score 4):

I am wondering two things:

1) bounds check:
define the BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS preprocessor macro prior to including multi_array.hpp in your application. This turns off bound checking. not sure if this this is disables when NDEBUG is.

2) base index:
 MultiArray can index arrays from bases different from 0. That means that multi_array stores a base number (in each dimension) and uses a more complicated formula to obtain the exact location in memory, I am wondering if it is all about that.

Otherwise I don't understand why multiarray should be slower than C-arrays.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking at this question because I had the same question. I had some thoughts to give a more rigorous test.

1. As [rodrigob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4220976/1695375) pointed out, there are flaws in the loop order such that any results in the code that you originally attached will give misleading data
2. Also, there are rather small sized arrays that are being set using constants. The compiler may be optimize out the loops, when in reality the compiler will not know the size of the arrays. The sizes of the arrays and number of iterations should be runtime inputs just in case.

On a Mac, the following code is configured to give more meaningful answers. There are 4 tests here.

```
#define BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include<string>

uint64_t GetTimeMs64()
{
  struct timeval tv;

  gettimeofday( &tv, NULL );

  uint64_t ret = tv.tv_usec;
  /* Convert from micro seconds (10^-6) to milliseconds (10^-3) */
  ret /= 1000;

  /* Adds the seconds (10^0) after converting them to milliseconds (10^-3) */
  ret += ( tv.tv_sec * 1000 );

  return ret;

}


void function1( const int X_SIZE, const int Y_SIZE, const int ITERATIONS )
{

  double nativeMatrix1add[X_SIZE*Y_SIZE];

  for( int x = 0 ; x < X_SIZE ; ++x )
  {
    for( int y = 0 ; y < Y_SIZE ; ++y )
    {
      nativeMatrix1add[y + ( x * Y_SIZE )] = rand();
    }
  }

  // Create the native array
  double* __restrict const nativeMatrix1p = new double[X_SIZE * Y_SIZE];
  uint64_t startTime = GetTimeMs64();
  for( int i = 0 ; i < ITERATIONS ; ++i )
  {
    for( int xy = 0 ; xy < X_SIZE*Y_SIZE ; ++xy )
    {
      nativeMatrix1p[xy] += nativeMatrix1add[xy];
    }
  }
  uint64_t endTime = GetTimeMs64();
  printf( "[Native Pointer]    Elapsed time: %6.3f seconds\n", ( endTime - startTime ) / 1000.0 );

}

void function2( const int X_SIZE, const int Y_SIZE, const int ITERATIONS )
{

  double nativeMatrix1add[X_SIZE*Y_SIZE];

  for( int x = 0 ; x < X_SIZE ; ++x )
  {
    for( int y = 0 ; y < Y_SIZE ; ++y )
    {
      nativeMatrix1add[y + ( x * Y_SIZE )] = rand();
    }
  }

  // Create the native array
  double* __restrict const nativeMatrix1 = new double[X_SIZE * Y_SIZE];
  uint64_t startTime = GetTimeMs64();
  for( int i = 0 ; i < ITERATIONS ; ++i )
  {
    for( int x = 0 ; x < X_SIZE ; ++x )
    {
      for( int y = 0 ; y < Y_SIZE ; ++y )
      {
        nativeMatrix1[y + ( x * Y_SIZE )] += nativeMatrix1add[y + ( x * Y_SIZE )];
      }
    }
  }
  uint64_t endTime = GetTimeMs64();
  printf( "[Native 1D Array]   Elapsed time: %6.3f seconds\n", ( endTime - startTime ) / 1000.0 );

}


void function3( const int X_SIZE, const int Y_SIZE, const int ITERATIONS )
{

  double nativeMatrix2add[X_SIZE][Y_SIZE];

  for( int x = 0 ; x < X_SIZE ; ++x )
  {
    for( int y = 0 ; y < Y_SIZE ; ++y )
    {
      nativeMatrix2add[x][y] = rand();
    }
  }

  // Create the native array
  double nativeMatrix2[X_SIZE][Y_SIZE];
  uint64_t startTime = GetTimeMs64();
  for( int i = 0 ; i < ITERATIONS ; ++i )
  {
    for( int x = 0 ; x < X_SIZE ; ++x )
    {
      for( int y = 0 ; y < Y_SIZE ; ++y )
      {
        nativeMatrix2[x][y] += nativeMatrix2add[x][y];
      }
    }
  }
  uint64_t endTime = GetTimeMs64();
  printf( "[Native 2D Array]   Elapsed time: %6.3f seconds\n", ( endTime - startTime ) / 1000.0 );

}



void function4( const int X_SIZE, const int Y_SIZE, const int ITERATIONS )
{

  boost::multi_array<double, 2> boostMatrix2add( boost::extents[X_SIZE][Y_SIZE] );

  for( int x = 0 ; x < X_SIZE ; ++x )
  {
    for( int y = 0 ; y < Y_SIZE ; ++y )
    {
      boostMatrix2add[x][y] = rand();
    }
  }

  // Create the native array
  boost::multi_array<double, 2> boostMatrix( boost::extents[X_SIZE][Y_SIZE] );
  uint64_t startTime = GetTimeMs64();
  for( int i = 0 ; i < ITERATIONS ; ++i )
  {
    for( int x = 0 ; x < X_SIZE ; ++x )
    {
      for( int y = 0 ; y < Y_SIZE ; ++y )
      {
        boostMatrix[x][y] += boostMatrix2add[x][y];
      }
    }
  }
  uint64_t endTime = GetTimeMs64();
  printf( "[Boost Array]       Elapsed time: %6.3f seconds\n", ( endTime - startTime ) / 1000.0 );

}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{

  srand( time( NULL ) );

  const int X_SIZE = std::stoi( argv[1] );
  const int Y_SIZE = std::stoi( argv[2] );
  const int ITERATIONS = std::stoi( argv[3] );

  function1( X_SIZE, Y_SIZE, ITERATIONS );
  function2( X_SIZE, Y_SIZE, ITERATIONS );
  function3( X_SIZE, Y_SIZE, ITERATIONS );
  function4( X_SIZE, Y_SIZE, ITERATIONS );

  return 0;
}
```

1. One with just a single dimensional array using the [] with integer math and a double loop
2. One with the same single dimensional array using pointer incrementing
3. A multidimensional C array
4. A boost multi_array

so run from a command line, run

```
./test_array xsize ysize iterations"
```

and you can get a good idea of how these approaches will perform. Here is what I got with the following compiler flags:

```
g++4.9.2 -O3 -march=native -funroll-loops -mno-avx --fast-math -DNDEBUG  -c -std=c++11


./test_array 51200 1 20000
[Native 1-Loop ]    Elapsed time:  0.537 seconds
[Native 1D Array]   Elapsed time:  2.045 seconds
[Native 2D Array]   Elapsed time:  2.749 seconds
[Boost Array]       Elapsed time:  1.167 seconds

./test_array 25600 2 20000
[Native 1-Loop ]    Elapsed time:  0.531 seconds
[Native 1D Array]   Elapsed time:  1.241 seconds
[Native 2D Array]   Elapsed time:  1.631 seconds
[Boost Array]       Elapsed time:  0.954 seconds

./test_array 12800 4 20000
[Native 1-Loop ]    Elapsed time:  0.536 seconds
[Native 1D Array]   Elapsed time:  1.214 seconds
[Native 2D Array]   Elapsed time:  1.223 seconds
[Boost Array]       Elapsed time:  0.798 seconds

./test_array 6400 8 20000
[Native 1-Loop ]    Elapsed time:  0.540 seconds
[Native 1D Array]   Elapsed time:  0.845 seconds
[Native 2D Array]   Elapsed time:  0.878 seconds
[Boost Array]       Elapsed time:  0.803 seconds

./test_array 3200 16 20000
[Native 1-Loop ]    Elapsed time:  0.537 seconds
[Native 1D Array]   Elapsed time:  0.661 seconds
[Native 2D Array]   Elapsed time:  0.673 seconds
[Boost Array]       Elapsed time:  0.708 seconds

./test_array 1600 32 20000
[Native 1-Loop ]    Elapsed time:  0.532 seconds
[Native 1D Array]   Elapsed time:  0.592 seconds
[Native 2D Array]   Elapsed time:  0.596 seconds
[Boost Array]       Elapsed time:  0.764 seconds

./test_array 800 64 20000
[Native 1-Loop ]    Elapsed time:  0.546 seconds
[Native 1D Array]   Elapsed time:  0.594 seconds
[Native 2D Array]   Elapsed time:  0.606 seconds
[Boost Array]       Elapsed time:  0.764 seconds

./test_array 400 128 20000
[Native 1-Loop ]    Elapsed time:  0.536 seconds
[Native 1D Array]   Elapsed time:  0.560 seconds
[Native 2D Array]   Elapsed time:  0.564 seconds
[Boost Array]       Elapsed time:  0.746 seconds
```

So, I think that it is safe to say that the boost multi_array performs pretty good. Nothing beats a single loop evaluation, but depending on the dimension of the array, the boost::multi_array may beat a standard c-array with a double loop.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to try is to use iterators instead of a straight index for the boost array.

Comment: Thanks for the idea - I'll test it. But as my ultimate goal is to refactor some code with native arrays to use boost, I'd rather not change all the existing [][] notation.

Answer (score 2):

I would have expected multiarray to be just as efficient.  But I'm getting similar results on a PPC Mac using gcc.  I also tried multiarrayref, so that both versions were using the same storage with no difference.  This is good to know, since I use multiarray in some of my code, and just assumed it was similar to hand-coding.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what the problem is...maybe.

In order for the boost implementation to have a syntax like: matrix[x][y]. that means that matrix[x] has to return a reference to an object which acts like a 1D array *column*, at which point reference[y] gives you your element.

The problem here is that you are iterating in **row major** order (which is typical in c/c++ since native arrays are row major IIRC. The compiler has to re-execute matrix[x] for each y in this case. If you iterated in column major order when using the boost matrix, you may see better performance.

Just a theory.

EDIT: on my linux system (with some minor changes) I tested my theory, and did show *some* performance improvement by switching x and y, but it was still slower than a native array. This might be a simple issue of the compiler not being able to optimize away the temporary reference type.

Answer (score 1):

Build in release mode, use objdump, and look at the assembly. They may be doing completely different things, and you'll be able to see which optimizations the compiler is using.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked and answered here:

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-300014.html

The short answer is that it is easiest for the compiler to optimize the simple arrays, and not so easy to optimize the Boost version.  Hence, a particular compiler may not give the Boost version all the same optimization benefits.

Compilers can also vary in how well they will optimize vs. how conservative they will be (e.g. with templated code or other complications).

Answer (score 1):

I tested on a Snow Leopard Mac OS using `gcc 4.2.1`

```
Debug:
[Boost] Elapsed time:  2.268 seconds
[Native]Elapsed time:  0.076 seconds

Release:
[Boost] Elapsed time:  0.065 seconds
[Native]Elapsed time:  0.020 seconds
```

Here, is the code (modified so that it can be compiled on Unix):

```
#define BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <ctime>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const int X_SIZE = 200;
    const int Y_SIZE = 200;
    const int ITERATIONS = 500;
    unsigned int startTime = 0;
    unsigned int endTime = 0;

    // Create the boost array
    typedef boost::multi_array<double, 2> ImageArrayType;
    ImageArrayType boostMatrix(boost::extents[X_SIZE][Y_SIZE]);

    // Create the native array
    double *nativeMatrix = new double [X_SIZE * Y_SIZE];

    //------------------Measure boost----------------------------------------------
    startTime = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < Y_SIZE; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < X_SIZE; ++x)
            {
                boostMatrix[x][y] = 2.345;
            }
        }
    }
    endTime = clock();
    printf("[Boost] Elapsed time: %6.3f seconds\n", (endTime - startTime) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    //------------------Measure native-----------------------------------------------
    startTime = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < Y_SIZE; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < X_SIZE; ++x)
            {
                nativeMatrix[x + (y * X_SIZE)] = 2.345;
            }
        }
    }
    endTime = clock();
    printf("[Native]Elapsed time: %6.3f seconds\n", (endTime - startTime) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the assembly generated by g++ 4.8.2 with `-O3 -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS` and using both the `operator()` and the `[][]` ways to access elements, it's evident that the only extra operation compared to native arrays and manual index calculation is the addition of the base. I didn't measure the cost of this though.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the above code in visual studio 2008 v9.0.21022 and applied the container routines from the Numerical Recipe routines for C and C++

http://www.nrbook.com/nr3/ using their licensed routines dmatrix and MatDoub respectively

dmatrix uses the out of date syntax malloc operator and is not recommended...
MatDoub uses the New command

The speed in seconds are in Release version:

Boost: 0.437

Native: 0.032

Numerical Recipes C: 0.031

Numerical recipes C++: 0.031

So from the above blitz looks like the best free alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I've compiled the code (with slight modifications) under VC++ 2010 with optimisation turned on ("Maximize Speed" together with inlining "Any Suitable" functions and "Favoring fast code") and got times 0.015/0.391. I've generated assembly listing and, though I'm a terrible assembly noob, there's one line inside the boost-measuring loop which doesn't look good to me:

```
call    ??A?$multi_array_ref@N$01@boost@@QAE?AV?$sub_array@N$00@multi_array@detail@1@H@Z ; boost::multi_array_ref<double,2>::operator[]
```

One of the [] operators didn't get inlined! The called procedure makes another call, this time to `multi_array::value_accessor_n<...>::access<...>()`:

```
call    ??$access@V?$sub_array@N$00@multi_array@detail@boost@@PAN@?$value_accessor_n@N$01@multi_array@detail@boost@@IBE?AV?$sub_array@N$00@123@U?$type@V?$sub_array@N$00@multi_array@detail@boost@@@3@HPANPBIPBH3@Z ; boost::detail::multi_array::value_accessor_n<double,2>::access<boost::detail::multi_array::sub_array<double,1>,double *>
```

Altogether, the two procedures are quite a lot of code for simply accessing a single element in the array. My general impression is that the library is so complex and high-level that Visual Studio is unable to optimise it as much as we would like (posters using gcc apparently have got better results).

IMHO, a good compiler really should have inlined and optimised the two procedures - both are pretty short and straight-forward, don't contain any loops etc. A lot of time may be wasted simply on passing their arguments and results.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by rodrigob, activating the proper optimization (GCC's default is -O0) is the key to get good performance. In addition, I also tested with [Blaze DynamicMatrix](https://bitbucket.org/account/user/blaze-lib/projects/BLAZE) , which yielded an additional factor 2 performance improvement with the exact same optimization flags. https://bitbucket.org/account/user/blaze-lib/projects/BLAZE

Answer (score 0):

I revisited a related question here: [Compare blitz++, armadillo, boost::MultiArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414906/compare-blitz-armadillo-boostmultiarray/77014134#77014134) (see details there).

Going back to this question and adding another library (MULTI) for comparison, I get:

```
$ sudo cpupower frequency-set --governor performance
$ g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG a.cpp && sudo nice -n -10 ./a.out
[Boost Loop] Elapsed time:  0.009 seconds
[Blitz Loop] Elapsed time:  0.007 seconds
[Native Loop] Elapsed time:  0.012 seconds
[MULTI Loop] Elapsed time:  0.007 seconds
```

```
$ sudo cpupower frequency-set --governor performance
$ g++ a.cpp && sudo nice -n -10 ./a.out
[Boost Loop] Elapsed time:  1.516 seconds
[Blitz Loop] Elapsed time:  0.221 seconds
[Native Loop] Elapsed time:  0.062 seconds
[MULTI Loop] Elapsed time:  1.527 seconds
```

---

Full code (adapted to Linux and std::chrono and preventing compiler from eliminating unused variables)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <blitz/array.h>
#include <armadillo>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include "/home/correaa/boost-multi/include/multi/array.hpp"

#include <chrono>
auto GetTickCount() {return chrono::steady_clock::now();}

template <class T>
void doNotOptimizeAway(T&& t) {
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("" :: "g" (t));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const int X_SIZE = 200;
    const int Y_SIZE = 200;
    double factor = 10;  // had to do more iteration to get more steady results, the timings are normalized still
    const int ITERATIONS = 500*10;
    auto startTime = ::GetTickCount();
    auto endTime = ::GetTickCount();

    // Create the boost array


    //------------------Measure boost Loop------------------------------------------
    {
        typedef boost::multi_array<double, 2> ImageArrayType;
        ImageArrayType boostMatrix(boost::extents[X_SIZE][Y_SIZE]);
        startTime = ::GetTickCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < X_SIZE; ++x)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < Y_SIZE; ++y)
                {
                    boostMatrix[x][y] = 1.0001;
                }
            }
            doNotOptimizeAway(boostMatrix);
        }
        endTime = ::GetTickCount();
        printf("[Boost Loop] Elapsed time: %6.3f seconds\n", chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(endTime - startTime).count() / 1000000000.0 / factor);
    }
    //------------------Measure blitz Loop-------------------------------------------
    {
        blitz::Array<double, 2> blitzArray( X_SIZE, Y_SIZE );
        startTime = ::GetTickCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < X_SIZE; ++x)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < Y_SIZE; ++y)
                {
                    blitzArray(x,y) = 1.0001;
                }
            }
            doNotOptimizeAway(blitzArray);
        }
        endTime = ::GetTickCount();
        printf("[Blitz Loop] Elapsed time: %6.3f seconds\n", chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(endTime - startTime).count() / 1000000000.0 / factor);
    }

    //------------------Measure armadillo loop----------------------------------------
    {
        arma::mat matArray( X_SIZE, Y_SIZE );
        startTime = ::GetTickCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Y_SIZE; ++y)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < X_SIZE; ++x)
                {
                    matArray(x,y) = 1.0001;
                }
            }
            doNotOptimizeAway(matArray);
        }
        endTime = ::GetTickCount();
        printf("[arma  Loop]  Elapsed time: %6.3f seconds\n", chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(endTime - startTime).count() / 1000000000.0 / factor);
    }

    //------------------Measure native loop----------------------------------------
    // Create the native array
    {
        double *nativeMatrix = new double [X_SIZE * Y_SIZE];
        startTime = ::GetTickCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Y_SIZE*X_SIZE; ++y)
            {
                nativeMatrix[y] = 1.0001;
            }
            doNotOptimizeAway(nativeMatrix);
        }
        endTime = ::GetTickCount();
        printf("[Native Loop] Elapsed time: %6.3f seconds\n", chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(endTime - startTime).count() / 1000000000.0 / factor);
        delete[] nativeMatrix;
    }
    //------------------Measure EIGEN Loop------------------------------------------
    {
        typedef Eigen::MatrixXd ImageArrayType;
        ImageArrayType eigenMatrix(X_SIZE, Y_SIZE);
        startTime = ::GetTickCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < X_SIZE; ++x)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < Y_SIZE; ++y)
                {
                    eigenMatrix(x, y) = 1.0001;
                }
            }
            doNotOptimizeAway(eigenMatrix);
        }
        endTime = ::GetTickCount();
        printf("[EIGEN Loop] Elapsed time: %6.3f seconds\n", chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(endTime - startTime).count() / 1000000000.0 / factor);
    }
    //------------------Measure Multi Loop------------------------------------------
    {
        typedef boost::multi::array<double, 2> ImageArrayType;
        ImageArrayType multiMatrix({X_SIZE, Y_SIZE});
        startTime = ::GetTickCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < X_SIZE; ++x)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < Y_SIZE; ++y)
                {
                    multiMatrix[x][y] = 1.0001;
                }
            }
            doNotOptimizeAway(multiMatrix);
        }
        endTime = ::GetTickCount();
        printf("[MULTI Loop] Elapsed time: %6.3f seconds\n", chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(endTime - startTime).count() / 1000000000.0 / factor);
    }

    return 0;
}
```