# A C++ library for Arrays, Matrix, Vector, and classical linear algebra operations

Tags: c++, arrays

Which library do you use for N-dimensional arrays?

I use blitz++ at work and I really dislike some aspect of it.
Some aspect of it are even dangerous.  The need for resizing before
using operator=. A(Range::all(), Range::all()) throws for an (0,0)
matrix, etc. and the linear algebra operations are to be
done via clapack.

I used and loved eigen. I appreciate its "all-in-header" implementations,
the C++ syntactic sugar, and the presence of all the linear algebra operations
I need (matrix multiplication, system resolution, cholesky...)

What are you using?

Comment: I get the feeling you are asking about what libraries people use for mathematical arrays, not "C++ arrays"? If so you should consider being more specific in your question :)

Comment: Why would you want "basic matrix operations" for arrays? Perhaps your question should be about *matrix* classes then.

Comment: what's wrong with something like clapack? (or why is it too "blunt"?) It's not really clear what it is you're looking for.

Comment: why not eigen then (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) ? looks fast and well-documented

Comment: This library supports linear algebra. see here: https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/master/include/multi/adaptors/blas/test/gemv.cpp#L62-65

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[boost::array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/array.html) and also [boost::MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html). There's also a pretty good linear algebra package in boost called [uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm)

Comment: or std::array, if you are using gcc with -std=c++0x

Comment: boost multiarrays are sloooow, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446866/boostmultiarray-performance-question

Answer (score 3):

There is also [**armadillo**](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) which I am using in some projects.  From their website:

> Armadillo is a C++ linear algebra library (matrix maths) aiming towards
>   a good balance between speed and ease
>   of use. Integer, floating point and
>   complex numbers are supported, as well
>   as a subset of trigonometric and
>   statistics functions. Various matrix
>   decompositions are provided through
>   optional integration with LAPACK and
>   ATLAS libraries.
>
> A delayed evaluation approach is employed (during compile time) to
>   combine several operations into one
>   and reduce (or eliminate) the need for
>   temporaries. This is accomplished
>   through recursive templates and
>   template meta-programming.
>
> This library is useful if C++ has been decided as the language of choice
>   (due to speed and/or integration
>   capabilities), rather than another
>   language like Matlab ® or Octave. It
>   is distributed under a license that is
>   useful in both open-source and
>   commercial contexts.
>
> Armadillo is primarily developed at NICTA (Australia), with
>   contributions from around the world.

Comment: +1 looks nice, "good balance".
Has anyone compared its speed to blitz, numpy ...
as in www.scipy.org/PerformancePython laplace.py ?

Comment: +1 for the need for empirical comparisons. We need some sort of library for that so that one could start to collect results for different compilers, OSs, ...

Answer (score 2):

We've used [TNT](http://math.nist.gov/tnt/) successfully for a number of years. There are sufficient issues, however, that we're moving toward an internally developed solution instead. The two biggest sticking points for us are that

- The arrays are not thread safe, even for read access, because they use a non-thread safe reference count.
- The arrays cause all sorts of problems when you write const-correct code.

If those aren't a problem then they're fairly convenient for a lot of common array tasks.