# C libraries for mathematical matrix operations

Tags: c, matrix, operations, math

I know there are some optimized algorithms around for all kind of matrix decompositions (QR decomposition, SVD,...), multiplications and the likes. Yet, I couldn't find a good overview. For C++, there is quite some useful information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860404/a-c-library-for-arrays-matrix-vector-and-classical-linear-algebra-operations), but I'm looking for those things in C.

Comment: Related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198991/recommendations-for-a-small-c-based-vector-and-matrix-library

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You did not mention whether you wanted an open-source or a commercial software, so here is a list containing both:

- [GNU Scientific Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) (GSL)
- [Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms](http://www.netlib.org/blas/faq.html) (BLAS)
- [Meschach](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~dstewart/meschach/)
- [Numerical Algorithms Group](http://www.nag.co.uk/nag-c-library) (NAG)

There was also this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198991/recommendations-for-a-small-c-based-vector-and-matrix-library) on the subject.

Comment: thx for the info and the link. I missed that question.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. Do you know any package (one of the answer maybe) that supports *matrix multiplication in parallel*?

Answer (score 5):

You might want to take a look at [BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/) and [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/). These are written in Fortran, but are callable from C, and are pretty much *the* standard libraries of this type.

Most serious linear algebra packages that I know of (MATLAB, Octave, NumPy) are built using these.

Comment: The problem is, for small matrices, they tend to spend more time classifying their arguments than actually doing math.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps GNU Scientific Library (GSL) would be of interest.

http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

Documentation topics: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/