# GCC Native matrix operations libraries

Tags: c++, g++, gcc9

I wonder there are any native matrices operation library that come with standard gcc/glibc/g++. installation. I see that there are many [third party libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501322/c-libraries-for-mathematical-matrix-operations) boost, armadillo etc. provide implementations.

But I am wondering with the newer gcc 9.2 version, If there are any native libraries that are offering matrix operations instead of using third party libraries.

Thanks

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) provides an overview about what is covered in std libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no matrix or linear algebra support in the C++ standard library as of C++20.

There is a [proposal to add linear algebra support to the C++ standard library, P1385R5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1385r5.pdf), targeted for C++23. Also video [C++Now 2019: Bob Steagall “Linear Algebra for the Standard C++ Library”](https://youtu.be/CslK9tu9ssA).