# What is the difference betwen boost::multi_array views and subarrays

Tags: c++, boost, multidimensional-array, boost-multi-array

After looking the documentation I cannot figure this one out.

I can write code such as

```
typedef boost::multi_array<boost::int32_t, 3> data_t;

// 3d --
typedef data_t::array_view<3>::type data_3d_view_t;

// 2d --
typedef data_3d_view_t::reference data_2d_subarray_t;
typedef data_t::array_view<2>::type data_2d_view_t;
```

Then I can access a 2d slice using via the types `data_2d_subarray_t` or `data_2d_view_t`.

What is the difference between them ? 
What can I do with one that I cannot do with the other ? 
Is it there any performance difference ?

Thanks a lot for clarifying this to me.
Best regards,
rodrigob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the table of [MultiView associated types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#id835500):

> reference  This is the reference type of the contained value. If NumDims == 1, then this is element&. Otherwise, this is the same type as template subarray::type.
>
> template array_view::type    This is the view type with Dims dimensions. It is returned by calling operator. It models MultiArray.

so they're different types, to start with. In this context, views represent a sort of subcollection of a MultiArray. They implement the MultiArray concept, but the elements they contain are actually elements of some other MultiArray. Views allow you to define a new [index](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/indices.html) into the elements of a MultiArray. For example, you could define a view that reverses the index, so that the first element of the view is the last element of the MultiArray. From the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#MultiArray):

> A view lets you treat a subset of the underlying elements in a MultiArray as though it were a separate MultiArray. Since a view refers to the same underlying elements, changes made to a view's elements will be reflected in the original MultiArray.

MultiArrays are defined recursively; a MultiArray of dimension *n* > 1 can be thought of as array of MultiArrays of dimension *n*-1, which are subarrays. The key difference between a subarray and a view is that you can slice a MultiArray into views of lower dimensions along any axis, including the major axis, but subarrays cannot be sliced along the major axis.

```
data_t d3(boost::extents[4][5][6]);
data_2d_view_t d2_view = d3[boost::indices[range(0,4,2)][1][range(0,6,3)]];
data_2d_subarray_t d2_sub = d3[1];
// the following, and anything like it, won't work 
data_2d_subarray_t d2_sub_b = d3[range(0,4,2)][0];
```

I don't believe there's any major performance difference, though this depends on what type of index you use when creating a view. Views might be slightly less performant, but not in a big-O sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! That is exactly what I was looking for ! Although based on my previous experience http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446866/boostmulti-array-performance-question/4220976#4220976 I would think that in general subarrays are much more performant than views (in a "k on the side of the big O" sense).